# JavaScript method returns multiple values

Tags: javascript, return

So I got this code:

```
function q(x, y, z) {
return  n = Math.floor(x+(x+y+z)/3),
        o = Math.floor(y+(x+y+z)/3),
        p = Math.floor(z+(x+y+z)/3),
        x -= n-(n+o+p)/6,
        y -= o-(n+o+p)/6,
        z -= p-(n+o+p)/6,
        n = n % 3232 + 3232,
        o = o % 3232 + 3232, 
        p = p % 3232 + 3232, 
        l = [ 1, 1, 0,    -1, 1, 0,     1,-1, 0,    
             -1,-1, 0,     1, 0, 1,    -1, 0, 1,
              1, 0,-1,    -1, 0,-1,     0, 1, 1]
}
```

It's obvious I got many questions, but if anyone understands, tell me please how could it look in more traditional appearance, like in Java, for example?

Comment: You can only return one value. But that value can be an array which contains your multiple values.

Comment: What result are you expecting to get from that function exactly? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: This code is not mine, I also was surprised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From MDN [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator), stating how the comma operator works:

> The comma operator evaluates each of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the last operand.

and [assignment operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators), stating that the "result" of the expression `xyzzy = 42` is what gets loaded into `xyzzy`.

> Chaining the assignment operator is possible in order to assign a single value to multiple variables.

So only *one* value is being returned, the thing you've assigned to `l`.

It's effectively the same as the more "conventional":

```
n = Math.floor(x+(x+y+z)/3);
o = Math.floor(y+(x+y+z)/3);
p = Math.floor(z+(x+y+z)/3);
:
l = [ 1, 1, 0,    -1, 1, 0,     1,-1, 0,    
     -1,-1, 0,     1, 0, 1,    -1, 0, 1,
      1, 0,-1,    -1, 0,-1,     0, 1, 1];
return l;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could return an object that contains the parameters you described by simply surrounding them with { } and changing = to : so that it becomes:

```
function q(x, y, z) {
return  {n: Math.floor(x+(x+y+z)/3),
        o: Math.floor(y+(x+y+z)/3),
        p: Math.floor(z+(x+y+z)/3),
        ...}
}
```

Be wary of the usage of x, y, z though as they are your function input parameters aswell.

If you then execute this function and store its value:

```
var result = q(1,2,3);
```

you can get each value by doing:

```
result.o;
result.p;
result.l;
```

Under the hood you are creating a wrapper object that contains each variable you wish to return.